# How to remove TLS dependencies from reqwest?

Tags: rust, reqwest

I am planning to do GET/POST methods using the [reqwest](https://crates.io/crates/reqwest) library. Unfortunately, I don't want to have any TLS dependencies: no openssl, native-tls, rust-nativetls, etc.

How can I disable it?

Answer (score 3):

Reqwest has different TLS functionality provided by [its feature flags](https://docs.rs/crate/reqwest/0.11.12/features) with the `"default-tls"` feature enabled by default. To disable it, you need to set `default-features=false` in your Cargo.toml:

```toml
[dependencies]
reqwest = { version = "0.11.12", default-features = false }
```